# How do i enable open choose file dialog in webview with cocoa swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa

When i press button, call choose file dialog of OS into webview, was to open, but not working.

[See the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k205T.png)

my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.webview.frameLoadDelegate = self
    self.webview.policyDelegate = self
    self.webview.mainFrame.load(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL) as URLRequest!)

    self.webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

}

func webView(sender: WebView!, runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener resultListener: WebOpenPanelResultListener!, allowMultipleFiles: Bool) {
            let openDialog = NSOpenPanel()
            if (openDialog.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK) {
                let fileName: String = (openDialog.url?.path)!
                resultListener.chooseFilename(fileName) // Use chooseFilenames for multiple files
            }
        }
```

I need to show this dialog, when click button:
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b04r4.png)

Anyone can help me? Grateful forever!!!!

Comment: you load it on viewDidLoad(), what do you want to do??

Comment: are you using UIWebView(deprecated)  or WKWebView ? Can you update your code with webview declaration and the url you are trying to load in webview ?

Comment: I need show window of mac to choose file into webview or some alert in javascript coming from webview